# MediaTomb UI Not working... I've done all the configuration.xml?

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, upnp, mediatomb

I'm running ubuntu server 12.04 and have recently installed mediatomb. A
fter following instruction and changed the configuration.xml accordingly I haven't been able to accesses the web interface... I have port forwarded... But nothing happened I've removed and then reinstalled mediatomb, install my SQL and squite... Please help

Ed

Answer (score 1):

modify /etc/mediatomb/config.xml

```
<ui enabled="yes" show-tooltips="yes">

 <import hidden-files="no">

 <filesystem-charset>UTF-8</filesystem-charset>

 <metadata-charset>UTF-8</metadata-charset>
```

this is for 12.04.